# How to display total comments

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

Whatsup codeigniters!
I want to display total comments of my blog that I am building with codeigniter.
In my controller I have:

```
   function index() {

          $data['query'] = $this->blog_model->get_all_entries();
          $this->load->view('blog/index',$data);
   }
```

Function index() gets all posts.
and I have

```
  public function post($id) {
          $data['query'] = $this->blog_model->get_post($id);
          $data['comments'] = $this->blog_model->get_post_comment($id);
          $data['post_id'] = $id;
          $data['total_comments'] = $this->blog_model->total_comments($id);
          $this->load->view('blog/index',$data,TRUE);

          $this->load->helper('form');
          $this->load->library(array('form_validation','session'));
          //validation rules for post function

          $this->form_validation->set_rules('commentor','Name','required');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Your email','required|valid_email');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment','Comment','required');

          if($this->blog_model->get_post($id))
          {
                 foreach($this->blog_model->get_post($id) as $row) 
                 {
                        //set page title
                        $data['title'] = $row->entry_name;
                 }
                 if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                 {
                        //if validation runs FALSE
                        $this->load->view('blog/post',$data);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                        //if valid
                        $name = $this->input->post('commentor');
                        $email = strtolower($this->input->post('email'));
                        $comment = $this->input->post('comment');
                        $post_id = $id;

                        $this->blog_model->add_new_comment($post_id,$name,$email,$comment);
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '1 new comment added!');
                        redirect('blog/post/'.$id);
                  }
           }
           else
                  show_404();
   }
```

Basically, post($id) gets a post with id (single post) and display comments. I can print total comments number in single post. But how do i print total comments number in index() function where all posts are listed. Thank you!

Comment: do you want total comments in blog or comment per post

Comment: Hi pramod I want to display total comments under each post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this active record

```
$this->db->select("post_id , count(comment) as total_comments");    
$this->db->group_by('post_id');
$query = $this->db->get('comments');
```

This generate this sql query

```
SELECT 
     post_id,
     count(comment) as total_comments
FROM comments
GROUP BY post_id
```

Means this selects posts , count of posts for each comment and seperate them by post. For understanding Here is the table Structure

```
Comments
id    count(comment)    post_id
```

Now the query will first fetch all the comments then it will use group by to seperate posts giving you total comments for each post.

Comment: Hey raheel this works, but I have  problem in loop  IN VIEW: <?php if($query):foreach($query as $post): ?>
<div id="post"><h2><a href="<?php echo site_url('blog/post')?>/<?php echo $post->entry_id;?>" rel="bookmark"><?php echo $post->entry_name;?></a></h2>
<h5>(<?php echo $post->entry_date;?>)</h5></br>
<h4><?php echo $post->entry_body; ?></h4></div>
<?php foreach($comment as $com):?>
<p> <?php echo $com->total_comment; ?><br>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php endforeach; else:?>
<h2>No entry yet yey yet!</h2>
<?php endif; ?> It return 3711 numbers together not under post1 3, post2 7 ,post3 1 ,post4 1

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this
in Model

```
public function fetch_all_comment()
{
      $query = $this->db->get('comments');
      return $query->result();
}
```

In Controller

```
$data['all_comments'] = $this->model_name->fetch_all_comment();
 $this->load->view('viewname',$data);
```

In View

For this you have to call model in your view. for example if you want to display post name.

Load Model in view

```
  foreach ($all_comments as $row)
        {
            echo $row->post;
          echo $total_no_post = $this->model_name->fetch_total_no_of_comment_in_post($row->postid);
        }
```

Count no of comment in this function **fetch_total_no_of_comment_in_post**

Comment: This displays comments, I understand,but I need to display total comments number under each post

Comment: @NewKid I have updated my answer plz check whether its helpful or not

Comment: Let me try it, i will uptade u soon